# Why was the Content-MD5 header base64-encoded?

Tags: http

So the Content-MD5 HTTP header has been removed because it wasn't implemented consistently. But looking at [The HTTP/1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.15), I saw this curious detail:

```
Content-MD5   = "Content-MD5" ":" md5-digest
md5-digest   = <base64 of 128 bit MD5 digest as per RFC 1864>
```

What's the use of base64-encoding an MD5 hash before transmission? Why would this:

```
Content-MD5: MTViMjlmZmRjZTY2ZTEwNTI3YTY1YmM2ZDcxYWQ5NGQ=
```

Have been better than just this?

```
Content-MD5: 15b29ffdce66e10527a65bc6d71ad94d
```

Comment: I suppose it's the base 64 encoding ***as opposed to the hex encoding*** of the binary hash value. Not binary → hex → base 64, but binary → base 64; which has clear size advantages.

Comment: [This looks a useful page](http://cloudway.io/post/base64-encoded-128-bit/) on the details/differences - seems it's used in AWS in places too.

Comment: @deceze Oh, of course! Encoding a 16-byte string of bits would come out shorter than encoding a 32-byte string of hex characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As deceze said in the comment, you're supposed to base64 the MD5 hash, rather than the hex representation of the MD5 hash. This would have resulted in the shorter header:

```
Content-MD5: FbKf/c5m4QUnplvG1xrZTQ==
```